# Android Notification - Small icon not working on some devices

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications, custom-notification

According to https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#java I am creating a notification correctly.

I expect something as:

[image]

My code is:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "channel")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.wesay_not)
                .setContentTitle(notification.title)
                .setContentText(notification.description)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setChannelId(context.getString(R.string.channel_id));
```

And the drawable is there:

[image]

However the device is showing the default android one, other applications seem to be showing the icon ok:

[image]

Comment: may be same name of multiple images causing this error

Answer (score 2):

Probably that device you are using is `xxxhdpi`. and somehow it is taking default icon for those devices.

I suggest you remove your default icon from your project if you are not using it. And you can use [Notification Icon Generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit) for generating icons for all size.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I just noticed that the XXHDPI icon is 128x128 and it should be 72x72, probably that has to do

Answer (score 0):

find default icon named "wesay_not" in whole project first. If found than replace it with actual icon with folder related size.